# Send a Single Email to Project Owner w/All Related Project Subtasks & w/All Project Notes

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a Javascript/appscript for an Appsheet app. I cant figure this out, if someone could please help.

I have Three Sheets:
Project
Subtasks
Notes

I would like to be able to send the Project owner an email, that includes the project name all of the tasks assigned to that project (relationship via PK/FK ID,Project Name) and all of the notes assigned to that project (same relationship as Notes PK/FK ID,Project Name) where the last_update column is within 24 hours of right now. (I.E any changes or creations made in the last 24 hours to any task or note)

- I have provided a sample of all the tables, their columns, and an ideal sample output
- Public link to my spreadsheet:
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FcOKVkhdjK-vGuFPWSR2ZreBYFI6EK7EnQj3yKPvttk/edit?usp=sharing

[idealOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hohP4.png)

Comment: You would be better off to provide a link to a public spreadsheet so that we can copy the data.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FcOKVkhdjK-vGuFPWSR2ZreBYFI6EK7EnQj3yKPvttk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In your situation, is it required to sort the data of "Task" and "Notes" in the email?

Comment: No, Task order does not matter. Notes preferablly sorted in the email by most recent (not required)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - The sample script is awesome, is there a way you could have it so it only includes notes and tasks where the last_update column is only for changes made within the last 24 hours.

Comment: @Tanaike - Awesome again! Had to change the sign of the first carrot so that now is greater then temp for it to work properly.
return now > temp && temp > before24h;

Comment: @Tanaike - Is it possible, for this to only run on a single project based on an API call/webhook? so it doesnt send an email for every single project. Just a single project from referenced row from a webhook/api/appsheet button?

Comment: @Tanaike - Thank you! Yes I will mark this as the answer and close the ticket!

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: @Tanaike - I have posted the new question, thank you again. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70230872/reference-a-specific-row-by-an-api-call-or-webhook-and-run-a-function-on-just-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create the email message by retrieving the values from 3 sheets as follows. (The following image is from your question.)

  [image]
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- From your comment of `Task order does not matter. Notes preferablly sorted in the email by most recent (not required)`, I thought that you might want to sort the values of only "Notes".

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please check the sheet names. And please run `myFunction`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve 3 sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheetITPM, sheetITPM_Tasks, sheetNotes] = ["ITPM", "ITPM_Tasks", "Notes"].map(e => ss.getSheetByName(e));

  // Retrieve IDs, names and emails.
  const values = sheetITPM.getRange("A2:J" + sheetITPM.getLastRow()).getValues().map(r => ({ id: r[0], name: r[1], email: r[9] }));

  // Retrieve Tasks.
  const tasks = sheetITPM_Tasks.getRange("A2:G" + sheetITPM_Tasks.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r[2]] = o[r[2]] ? [...o[r[2]], { description: r[3], status: r[4], dueDate: r[6] }] : [{ description: r[3], status: r[4], dueDate: r[6] }], o), {});

  // Retrieve Notes.
  const notes = sheetNotes.getRange("A2:E" + sheetNotes.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r[1]] = o[r[1]] ? [...o[r[1]], { note: r[2], date: r[4] }] : [{ note: r[2], date: r[4] }], o), {});
  Object.entries(notes).forEach(([, v]) => v.sort((a, b) => a.date.getTime() < b.date.getTime() ? 1 : -1)); // If you don't want to sort the values of "Notes", please remove this line.

  // Send emails.
  values.forEach(({ id, name, email }) => {
    const message = [
      `Here is the project update for: ${name}`,
      "",
      `Assigned Tasks:`,
      ...tasks[id].map(({ description, status, dueDate }, i) => [`Task ${i + 1}:`, description, status, dueDate, ""].join("\n")),
      "",
      `Project Notes:`,
      ...notes[id].map(({ note }, i) => [`Note ${i + 1}:`, note, ""].join("\n")),
    ].join("\n");
    MailApp.sendEmail({ to: email, subject: "Project update", body: message });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the emails are sent by retrieving the values from 3 sheets. The email addresses are used from the column "J" of "ITPM" sheet.

#### Note:

- **This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. So when the structure of the Spreadsheet is changed from your sample Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this. When you test this script, please use your this sample Spreadsheet.**

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)

### Added:

OP's following new question,

> Is it possible to have it only include the notes and tasks where their column last update is within 24 hours of right now?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Retrieve 3 sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheetITPM, sheetITPM_Tasks, sheetNotes] = ["ITPM", "ITPM_Tasks", "Notes"].map(e => ss.getSheetByName(e));

  // Retrieve IDs, names and emails.
  const values = sheetITPM.getRange("A2:J" + sheetITPM.getLastRow()).getValues().map(r => ({ id: r[0], name: r[1], email: r[9] }));

  // Retrieve Tasks.
  const tasks = sheetITPM_Tasks.getRange("A2:G" + sheetITPM_Tasks.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r[2]] = o[r[2]] ? [...o[r[2]], { description: r[3], status: r[4], dueDate: r[6] }] : [{ description: r[3], status: r[4], dueDate: r[6] }], o), {});

  // Retrieve Notes.
  const notes = sheetNotes.getRange("A2:E" + sheetNotes.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r[1]] = o[r[1]] ? [...o[r[1]], { note: r[2], date: r[4] }] : [{ note: r[2], date: r[4] }], o), {});
  Object.entries(notes).forEach(([, v]) => v.sort((a, b) => a.date.getTime() < b.date.getTime() ? 1 : -1)); // If you don't want to sort the values of "Notes", please remove this line.

  // By OP's new question, I added the following script.
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const before24h = now - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  Object.entries(tasks).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    tasks[k] = v.filter(({dueDate}) => {
      const temp = dueDate.getTime();
      return now < temp && temp > before24h;
    });
  });
  Object.entries(notes).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    notes[k] = v.filter(({date}) => {
      const temp = date.getTime();
      return now < temp && temp > before24h;
    });
  });

  // Send emails.
  values.forEach(({ id, name, email }) => {
    const message = [
      `Here is the project update for: ${name}`,
      "",
      `Assigned Tasks:`,
      ...tasks[id].map(({ description, status, dueDate }, i) => [`Task ${i + 1}:`, description, status, dueDate, ""].join("\n")),
      "",
      `Project Notes:`,
      ...notes[id].map(({ note }, i) => [`Note ${i + 1}:`, note, ""].join("\n")),
    ].join("\n");
    MailApp.sendEmail({ to: email, subject: "Project update", body: message });
  });
}
```

- But, about your new question, when your sample Spreadsheet is used, in this case, `tasks` and `notes` are no values. Please be careful this.

Comment: This is awesome! Is it possible to have it only include the notes and tasks where their column last update is within 24 hours of right now?

Comment: @Brandon Ekbatani Thank you for replying. About your new question of `Is it possible to have it only include the notes and tasks where their column last update is within 24 hours of right now?`, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?